# Kinect sdk 2.0 third party library in C# support posture and gesture recognition?

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-v2

For Kinect sdk 2.0, is there any third-party library in C# that support posture and gesture recognition? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I read the rules, just tell me which rules did I violate here?

Comment: "Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check this out https://github.com/lightbuzz/vitruvius .

Answer (score -1):

For third-party library in C#, I highly recommend [Vitruvius](https://vitruviuskinect.com/). Other than gestures they also provide much more solutions that the Kinect can solve. They are also responsive to emails and queries sent to them.

I have a github repository using that third-party library with **guide and documentation** take a look at it here: https://github.com/bingcheng45/VitruviusGestureExample

Also, do take a look at this important video fully which helped me a lot along the ways from Microsoft which touch on gestures and positions: https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/k4wdev/Custom-Gestures-End-to-End-with-Kinect-and-Visual-Gesture-Builder

Do tell me if you find it helpful :D